# Conversion an output of UUT in test bench?

Tags: vhdl

UUT

```
component uut_test IS
    port (
            clk : in std_logic;
            rst : in std_logic;
            data_in1 : in integer; 
            data_out : out integer
        );
    end component main_integer;
```

I would like to get `data_out` as `std_logic_vector`.  In the test bench it was implemented as :

```
signal data_out: std_logic_vector( 3 downto 0); 
 
begin
UUT : main_integer
PORT MAP
    (
     clk => clk,
     rst => rst,
      data_in1 => conv_integer(data_in1),
      conv_std_logic_vector(data_out) => data_out
     );
```

I got the following error:

> ERROR: [XSIM 43-3294] Signal EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION received.

This error appeared if I convert to std_logic_vector.

```
conv_std_logic_vector(data_out) => data_out
```

PS I know I can convert it in Behavioral file ( design).

Comment: You can't do that kind of conversion in a `port map`. You have to do it as a separate step.

Comment: @DaveTweed I did it for input vector and it works.  I converted it to integer. Why doesnt it work for output then?

Comment: @DaveTweed separate step? What do you mean? Step in test bench ?

Comment: It worked for input because that's on the right-hand side of the map. You can't call a function on the left-hand side of a map.

Comment: A separate step like how @MituRaj did it below.

Comment: @DaveTweed  Type conversions can be placed on the formal of a port map for out and inout mode.   However, it must have only one parameter.   What the OP is not showing is that either this is a custom conv_std_logic_vector or it uses two parameters since it has to some how produce the correct size for the std_logic_vector version of data_out.  If it has two parameters, it is no longer a conversion and is indeed illegal.   
VHDL-2019 will allow a more general single parameter function call when the size of the actual port is known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an internal signal:

```
signal uut_data_out : integer ;
```

Map `data_out` of UUT like this:

```
data_out => uut_data_out
```

Concurrently assign `data_out` like this:

```
data_out <= conv_std_logic_vector (uut_data_out, 4) ;
```

Comment: How does conv_std_logic_vector create a correct sized std_logic_vector with only a single parameter?   Without VHDL-2019, it is either a custom function or it has a second parameter that the OP left out.

Comment: I haven't used this function because it's from std_arith, but you seem to be right. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/13.0/mergedProjects/hdl/vhdl/vhdl_pro_conversion.htm